# Elasticsearch : Completion suggester not working with whitespace Analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, autosuggest, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-6

I am new to Elastic search and I am trying to create one demo of **Completion suggester** with **whitespace Analyzer**.

> As per the documentation of [Whitespace Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html), It breaks text
>   into terms whenever it encounters a whitespace character. So my
>   question is do it works with Completion suggester too?
>
> **So for my completion suggester prefix : "ela",** **I am expecting output
>   as "Hello elastic search."**

**I know an easy solution for this is to add multi-field input as :**

```
"suggest": {
         "input": ["Hello","elastic","search"]
 }
```

> **However, if this is the solution then what is meaning of using analyzer? Does analyzer make sense in completion suggester?**

My mapping :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "completion_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
            "my-type": {
                "properties": {
                    "mytext": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "suggest": {
                        "type": "completion",
                        "analyzer": "completion_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "completion_analyzer",
                        "max_input_length": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My document :

```
{
    "_index": "my-index",
    "_type": "my-type",
    "_id": "KTWJBGEBQk_Zl_sQdo9N",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "mytext": "dummy text",
        "suggest": {
                 "input": "Hello elastic search."
        }
    }
}
```

Search request :

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "test-suggest" : {
        "prefix" :"ela", 
        "completion" : { 
            "field" : "suggest",
            "skip_duplicates": true
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**This search is not returning me the correct output, but if I use prefix = 'hel' I am getting correct output : "Hello elastic search."**

In brief I would like to know is whitespace Analyzer works with completion suggester?
and if there is a way, can you please suggest me.

PS: I have already look for this links but I didn't find useful answer.

[ElasticSearch completion suggester Standard Analyzer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209957/elasticsearch-completion-suggester-standard-analyzer-not-working)

[What Elasticsearch Analyzer to use for this completion suggester?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899480/what-elasticsearch-analyzer-to-use-for-this-completion-suggester)

I find this link useful [Word-oriented completion suggester (ElasticSearch 5.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744712/word-oriented-completion-suggester-elasticsearch-5-x/41800102#41800102). However they have not use completion suggester.

Thanks in advance.

Jimmy

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with a custom analyzer, it seems completion doesn't take into account the output of the analyzer somehow

Comment: yes, something is not correct with analyzer in completion suggester. Finally I end up using alternate solution to add multiple tags in input array instead expected approach.

Comment: What I'm exploring for my use case are nGrams instead.

Comment: @pcambra oh okay. I tried above approach with edge-ngrams and it was working correctly. you can try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744712/word-oriented-completion-suggester-elasticsearch-5-x I implemented the procedure given in accepted answer and it was working well for my requirement. Only thing is we can't skip duplicate with ngram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The completion suggester cannot perform full-text queries, which means that it cannot return suggestions based on words in the middle of a multi-word field.

From [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me) itself:

> The reason is that an FST query is not the same as a full text query. We can't find words anywhere within a phrase. Instead, we have to start at the left of the graph and move towards the right.

As you discovered, the best alternative to the completion suggester that *can* match the middle of fields is an edge n-gram filter.

Answer (score 2):

gI know this question is ages old, but have you tried have multiple suggestions, one based on prefix and the next one based in regex ?

Something like

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "test-suggest-exact" : {
            "prefix" :"ela", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "suggest",
                "skip_duplicates": true
            }
        },
        "test-suggest-regex" : {
            "regex" :".*ela.*", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "suggest",
                "skip_duplicates": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use results from the second suggest when the first one is empty. The good thing is that meaningful phrases are returned by the Elasticsearch suggest.

Shingle based approach, using a full query search and then aggregating based on search terms sometimes gives broken phrases which are contextually wrong. I can write more if you are interested.